# x-on:click not working in alpine.js for tabs

Tags: alpine.js

I'm new to using alpine.js, coming from jquery. I cant for the life of me figure out why the x-on:click events are not working properly. Even when I remove the data portion of the click and just try to console.log, nothing is happening. I'm using alpine.js with Laravel and Breeze. this is my blade template:

```html
<x-app-layout>
    <div x-data="{ tab: 'posts' }">
        <x-slot name="header">
            <div class="flex justify-between w-full items-center">
                <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 leading-tight">
                    Hello, {{ explode(' ', Auth::user()->name)[0] }}! 
                </h2>
                <div class="flex space-x-2">
                    <button x-on:click="tab = 'posts'; console.log('Tab changed to:', tab)" :class="{ 'bg-blue-700': tab === 'posts' }"
                        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Posts</button>
                        <button x-on:click="tab = 'workHistory'; console.log('Tab changed to:', tab)" :class="{ 'bg-blue-700': tab === 'workHistory' }"
                        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Work
                        History</button>
                    <button x-on:click="tab = 'projects'; console.log('Tab changed to:', tab)" :class="{ 'bg-blue-700': tab === 'projects' }"
                        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Projects</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Dropdown Component -->

            </div>
        </x-slot>

        <!-- Tab Content -->
        <div class="container mx-auto py-6">
            <!-- Posts Section -->
            <div x-show="tab === 'posts'">
                <div class="py-2">
                    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        @foreach ($posts as $post)
                        <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->slug) }}" class="flex-grow">
                            <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg mb-6">
                                <div class="flex justify-center">
                                    <h3
                                        class="text-xl font-bold p-2 text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 border-b border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-700 pb-4 mb-1">
                                        {{ strip_tags($post->title) }}</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="p-4 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 flex justify-between items-center">
                                    <p class="text-sm font-body text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-300 mt-2">{!!
                                        Str::limit($post->content, 35) !!}</p>
                                    <div class="button-group inline flex">
                                        <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}"
                                            class="inline-block bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit
                                        </a>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $post->id) }}" method="POST"
                                            class="inline">
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                class="inline-block bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete
                                            </button>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div x-show="tab === 'workHistory'">
                <!-- Work History Section -->
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <h3 class="text-xl font-bold text-gray-800 dark:text-white mb-4 text-center">Work History</h3>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4 justify-center">
                        @foreach($work_histories as $work)
                        <div
                            class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 rounded-lg shadow overflow-hidden mb-4 flex flex-col h-full">
                            <img class="h-40 w-40 object-cover mt-2 mx-auto" src="{{ asset($work->image) }}"
                                alt="Work History Image">
                            <div class="flex flex-col flex-grow p-4 text-center">
                                <h4 class="font-bold text-lg dark:text-white">{{ $work->title }}</h4>
                                <h4 class="font-bold text-lg dark:text-white mb-2">{{ $work->company }}</h4>
                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-300 flex-grow">
                                    {{ $work->description }}
                                </p>
                                <div class="flex justify-end px-1 pb-2">
                                    <div class="button-group inline flex">
                                        <a href="{{ route('work_history.edit', $work->id) }}"
                                            class="inline-block bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit
                                        </a>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <form action="{{ route('work_history.destroy', $work->id) }}" method="POST"
                                            class="inline">
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                class="inline-block bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete
                                            </button>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="border-t border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600 px-4 py-2">
                                <p class="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-right">
                                    {{ $work->start_date }} - {{ $work->end_date ?? 'Present' }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Projects Tab Content -->
            <div x-show="tab === 'projects'">
                <!-- Projects Section -->
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <h3 class="text-xl font-bold text-gray-800 dark:text-white mb-4 text-center">Projects</h3>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4 justify-center">
                        @foreach($projects as $project)
                        <div
                            class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 rounded-lg shadow overflow-hidden mb-4 flex flex-col h-full">
                            <img class="h-40 w-40 object-cover mt-2 mx-auto" src="{{ asset($project->image) }}"
                                alt="Work History Image">
                            <div class="flex flex-col flex-grow p-4 text-center">
                                <h4 class="font-bold text-lg dark:text-white">{{ $project->title }}</h4>
                                <p class="text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-300 flex-grow">
                                    {{ $project->description }}</p>
                                <div class="flex justify-end px-1 pb-2">
                                    <div class="button-group inline flex">
                                        <a href="{{ route('projects.edit', $project->id) }}"
                                            class="inline-block bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit
                                        </a>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <form action="{{ route('projects.destroy', $project->id) }}" method="POST"
                                            class="inline">
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                class="inline-block bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete
                                            </button>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="border-t border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600 px-4 py-2">
                                <p class="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-right">
                                    {{ $project->created_at }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Comment: It seems all right. Have you installed AlpineJS?

Comment: yes alpine is installed and working. I've noticed if i move the tabs out of the x-slot the functionality works correctly. getting closer!

Comment: Can you publish the *app-layout* component?